# Trying to add arabic numeric support to a working regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm validating phone numbers with the following regex

`^((\+\d{1,3}(-|.| )?\(?\d\)?(-| |.)?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-|.| )?(\d{3,4})(-|.| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$`

and it's working perfectly.

I need to add Arabic numbers support e.g. "٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩"

I already did some research and found out that the \u0660 and \u0669 counts from 0 to 9 in Arabic, but I need this added into my working regex.

Thanks

Comment: `\x{0660}` represents a unicode character inside a regular expression. Just replace the numbers accordingly.

Comment: @icecub ... i am testing the regex on https://regex101.com and i can't seem to figure out where to add what you just mentioned .. i am not very good at modifying regex tbh

Comment: Can't really help you there either. Your regex is quite complicated. Aside from that, I have no idea what the correct arabic number format is. Like what does is start with? How many numbers does it contain? Etc etc

Comment: Seems you'd have to replace any occurence of `\d` with `[\d\x{0660}-\x{0669}]`. You could alternatively use the u flag to turn on unicode support (but \d will then match all unicode digits, not only arabic and latin)

Comment: @SebastianProske You're correct, although the u flag is not needed with `\x{...}`. It's only needed when you want `\d` to accept unicode digits.

Comment: @icecub that's what i wanted to say - either use the combined character class or turn on unicode support. Have worded my comment a bit different.

Comment: @SebastianProske I think you should turn it into an answer. Even if you don't write the correct regex for OP, it's good info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the pattern. Just do:

```
$temp = str_replace(['٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'], range(0, 9), $input);`
```

Then run the test on the temporary variable. Sorry, first array is back to front, visually but byte order should be right.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your pattern, so that `\d` is replaced by `[\d\x{0660}-\x{0669}]` for every occurance of `\d`. `\x{....}` is used to represent a specific character with the given hex-code and you can also apply ranges with these. The same can be done in Javascript by using `\u....`, so your pattern would be `[\d\u0660-\u0669]`.

You could alternatively turn on the `u`-flag (unicode) for your pattern, which then will cause `\d` to match any unicode digit (including latin and arabic, but not restricted to them). It will also affect other tokens like `\w` and `[[:alpha:]]`, but that should not be an issue here.

Comment: Here's what working so far

`^((\+[\d\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{1,3}(-|.| )?\(?[\d\x{0660}-\x{0669}]\)?(-| |.)?[\d\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{1,5})|(\(?[\d\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{2,6}\)?))(-|.| )?([\d\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{3,4})(-|.| )?([\d\x{0660}-\x{0669}]{4}){0,1}$`

How do i support this regex in JS aswell ?

Comment: Should be `[\d\u0660-\u0669]` in JS.